# What is the "realization" of a function?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory

I'm reading the textbook "Monotone Operators in Banach Space and Nonlinear Partial Differential Equation" and I found a term that I'm not familiar with and I can't find a proper definition.

> Let $X$ be a reflexive Banach space with dual $X'$, $H$ a Hilbert
>   space such that $X$ is dense and continuously embedded in $H$. Suppose
>   we are given a (not necessarily linear) function $A: X\to X'$. $A$ is
>   known to map $L^2(0,T;X)$ into $L^2(0,T;X')$, i.e., the
>   **realization** of $A: X\to X'$ as an operator on $L^2(0,T;X)$ has values in $L^2(0,T;X')$.

What is a "realization"?

Comment: What are $T$ and this $L^2$ notation?

Comment: Oh, sorry. $T>0$ is a real number and $L^2(0,T,X) = \{u:[0,T]\to X : \int_0^T \|u(t)\|_Xdt <\infty \}$

Comment: I made a mistake, $L^2(0,T;X)=\{u:[0,T] \to X:\int_0^T∥u(t)∥_X^2dt < \infty}

Comment: @JuanDavidSamboní Note that you can edit your own comments within $5$ minutes, and otherwise you can always delete them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map $A$ has domain $X$ and codomain $X'$, so it **is** not a map from $L^2([0,T],X)$ to $L^2([0,T],X')$. But it does induce such a map naturally, by setting $\tilde {A}(\phi)=A\circ \phi$ where $\phi\in L^2([0,T],X)$.

The author simply does not want to bother using a different notation for $A$ and $\tilde A$. Note that the actual point of the author is that the map $A\circ \phi$ lies in $L^2$ as well.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you very much

Comment: @JuanDavidSamboní You're welcome.